# How to get a value from related object in a django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm quite new with python and django and I apologize if the topic was already covered, but I coudln't find an answer to my question.

I have theese classes in my models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.category_type

class Area(models.Model):
    area_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.area_type

class Topic(models.Model):
    topic_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.topic_type

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag_type

class GenericRecord(models.Model):
    document_title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    category = models.ForeignKey("Category")
    area = models.ForeignKey("Area")
    topic = models.ForeignKey("Topic")
    tag = models.ForeignKey("Tag")
    note = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    link = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    file_upload = models.FileField(upload_to='GenericRecord/', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Document(GenericRecord):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    issue_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    validation_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)

    def get_admin_url(self):
        return reverse("admin:%s_%s_change" % (self._meta.app_label, self._meta.model_name), args=(self.id,))

    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.code:
            return "%s-%s" % (self.code, self.document_title)
        else:
            return "--%s" % self.document_title
```

And this piece of code in views.py

```
def documents_list(request):
    # Generate counts of some of the main objects
    num_docs=Document.objects.all().count()
    docs=Document.objects.all() 
    num_articles=Article.objects.all().count()
    articles=Article.objects.all()
    template='documents_management.html'

    for object in docs:
        object.fields = dict((field.name, field.value_to_string(object)) for field in object._meta.fields)

    # Render the HTML template documents_management.html with the data in the context variable
    return render(request,template,  context={'docs':docs, 'num_docs':num_docs,'docs':docs, 'num_articles':num_articles, 'articles':articles})
```

In the template I'm trying to get a table with all the values, but for the related objects I get the primary key (of course).

Here is the code in my template:

```
<table class="w3-table-all">
    {% for object in docs %}
        {%if forloop.first %}

            <tr>
            {% for field, value in object.fields.iteritems %}
                <th>{{ field }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
            </tr>

        {%endif%}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for object in docs %}    
        {% for field, value in object.fields.iteritems %}

             <td>{{ value }}</td>

        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

[What I see in my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsEd1.png)

My question is, how can I get the object Category, Area etc... in order to get the category_type, area_type etc. value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an great example from the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/#use-the-template-system

What you are searching for is the `question.choice_set.all` part.

**UPDATE due to a hint of bad style**

As mentioned by daniel you should ditch the `Field.to_value_string` method.

Since I am not a fan of implicit code I always recommend to code templates as explicit as possible, here would by my version of your template

```
<table class="w3-table-all">
    {% for doc in docs %}

        {% if forloop.first %}
            <tr>
                <th>Document Title</th>
                <th>Category Type</th>
                <th>Area Type</th>
                <th>...</th>
            </tr>
        {% else %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ doc.document_title }}</td>
                <td>{{ doc.category.category_type }}</td>
                <td>{{ doc.area.area_type }}</td>
                <td>...</td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

What I changed:

- only one for loop, you started with the `if forloop.first` you might also finish with the else case
- refactored `object` to `doc` because objects is used often within django for model managers
- add the fields explicit `doc.area.area_type`, this will prevent a new field in the model to also appear in the template but here I recommend an explicit over an implicit coding style

Also you can remove this from `document_list`:

```
for object in docs:
    object.fields = dict((field.name, field.value_to_string(object)) for field in object._meta.fields)
```

Comment: This is for reverse relations. OP wants to show forward relations.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17523854)

Comment: Hey, thx for the Feedback you are absolutely right. I updated my answer to hopefully make up for it ^^

Comment: @JohannesReichard I get your point. Actually, in the first version of my template I used the explicit code (even though without the improvement you suggest); Since the developpment of this project is also an exercise, I was just curious about how to do it in another way. I'm now trying to "order" the values... Thank you for your feedback and suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your use of `Field.value_to_string`. As the docstring on that method shows, this is for serialization, not for displaying values.

A much simpler and more effective way of doing this would be to use `getattr`, which gets the actual value; the template will then take care of converting those to a string, which in the case of the foreign keys will call the `__unicode__` method of the related objects.

```
object.fields = dict((field.name, getattr(obj, field.name)) for field in object._meta.fields)
```